# How to do Partial Data Update in Mule

Tags: dataweave, mule4

How i can do partial data update in mule . In Spring we used some approach like this .

```
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-partial-update
```

is there anything simple or similar in Mule .  Say if i am accepting 5 fields in my input payload which needs to be updated instead of uploading entire table( my table have 100 fields) i just needs to be updated only those 5 fields . In mule if i am using update i have to manually create all the queries to update.

Comment: What is the use case? Is it related to database update operation. You should provide a concrete example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using the [update](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/dw-values-functions-update) function in DataWeave 2.0 ?

Comment: Yes, but spring provides lot of flexibility like dto patterns, custom queries.